# Mark an appointment as Scheduled in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a Silverlight application that creates an appointment but since it's not marked as "Scheduled" it will not show up in the Calendar. I am using the SOAP service for this, and here is some sample code that fires on a button click that creates an appointment but it does not show up in the Calendar:

```
TestCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
{
    var soapCtx = ServiceHelper.GetSingletonSoapService();
    var activityId = Guid.NewGuid();
    var appt = new Entity()
    {
        Id = activityId,
        LogicalName = "appointment"
    };

    appt["activityid"] = activityId;
    appt["scheduledstart"] = DateTime.Now.Date;
    appt["scheduledend"] = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(1);
    appt["description"] = "Test 1 2 3";
    appt["subject"] = "Test Command Button Appointment";
    appt["location"] = "Location 1 2 3";

    soapCtx.BeginCreate(appt, ar =>
        {
            var response = soapCtx.EndCreate(ar);                                           
            var bookRequest = new OrganizationRequest();

            bookRequest.RequestName = "Book";
            bookRequest["Target"] = appt;
            soapCtx.BeginExecute(bookRequest, 
                new AsyncCallback(OnBookRequestedCompleted), soapCtx);

        }, null);                

});

void OnBookRequestedCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var soapCtx = (IOrganizationService)ar.AsyncState;
    var response = soapCtx.EndExecute(ar);      
}
```

I keep getting "NotFound" exception in the OnBookRequestedCompleted method. Is there a different way of doing this?

Comment: sorry if I am being thick, but surely you just need to set the statusreason to "Scheduled" when you create the record?

Comment: @AdamV have you tried this? I remember doing this but it had no effect. I believe the reason that changing a status of an appointment is a separate request is because it does some validation to see if there are any conflicts and if it does find any conflicts, it will report them and you can handle them however you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Use Fiddler to debug your HTTP request/response and this will give you details about the 'Not Found' exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be setting the ActivityId field it is returned by the BookRequest. if BookResponse.ValidationResult.ValidationSuccess == true, apptId = BookResponse.ValidationResult.ActivityId

You need to call SetStateRequest with the id returned by the BookRequest to set the state to Scheduled

For example:

```
                SetStateRequest state = new SetStateRequest();
                state.State = new OptionSetValue(3);   // Scheduled
                state.Status = new OptionSetValue(5);  // Busy
                state.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("appointment", apptId);
                SetStateResponse stateSet = (SetStateResponse)this.orgService.Execute(state);
```